# Backup failed on fresh Ubuntu 17.10 installation

Tags: backup, 17.10

I just installed a fresh version of 17.10 and want to set up a backup folder with the pre installed tool.

As the default settings, it saves the `/home` directory and ignores the trash and `~/Downloads`.

I set the backup location to `var/backups`.

When starting the first backup, it stops after a few seconds and prints out this error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1546, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1540, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1391, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1510, in do_backup
    full_backup(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 575, in full_backup
    globals.backend)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 456, in write_multivol
    (tdp, dest_filename, vol_num)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 146, in schedule_task
    return self.__run_synchronously(fn, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 172, in __run_synchronously
    ret = fn(*params)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 455, in <lambda>
    vol_num: put(tdp, dest_filename, vol_num),
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 344, in put
    backend.put(tdp, dest_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 376, in inner_retry
    % exception_traceback())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/util.py", line 52, in exception_traceback
    return uexc(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/util.py", line 80, in uexc
    e = unicode(e).encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 736: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yoy should set the backup *location* in a different drive where you (your user) have read/write permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a specific location that is recommended for backups?

Comment: Typically in an external drive or network share. Or other internal but different drive. There's no point in saving the backup to the same drive because if it fails both the original data and the backup will be gone.

Comment: I had duplicity configured and running normally for a while, but yesterday it had crashed with exactly the same stack trace. So, it's most likely a bug, which appeared after a recent package update.

Comment: There is a similar bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/1729695

Answer (score 0):

I too had backups working well, and then this exact same backtrace occurred.  I'm also using Ubuntu 17.10.  I found that the microSD card I was backing up to was read only for some reason.  Removing it and carefully inserting it solved my problem.